# Displaying output of the sum of three textboxes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how would I display the output of the sum of three textboxes?

This is my current javascript code

```
function sum() {       
            var result = parseInt(text1) + parseInt(text2) + parseInt(text3);
            if(!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementByID(sum).value = result;
            }
```

I have named the three textboxes in HTML as "text1" "text2" and "text3" accordingly

Also, I want to output this in HTML next to 'The sum of the numbers are:' how could i do this?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Only that it doesn't show "The sum of the numbers are:"?

Comment: Replace your 'document.getElementByID(sum)' by 'document.getElementById(sum)'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
<label for='txt1'>First Num:</label>
<input type='text' id='txt1' />
<br>
<label for='txt2'>Second Num:</label>
<input type='text' id='txt2' />
<br>
<label for='txt3'>Third Num:</label>
<input type='text' id='txt3' />
<br>
<button onclick="sum()">Get Sum</button>
<p id='sum'></p>
<script>
    function sum() {
        var text1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt1').value),
            text2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt2').value),
            text3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt3').value);

        var total = text1 + text2 + text1;

        if(!isNaN(total)) {
               document.getElementById('sum').innerText = 'The sum of the numbers are: ' + total;
        }
    }
</script>
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5xqa6eyj/4/)