# Output a result of numbers

Tags: javascript, html, output

For some reason my code will not work and I need help with outputing the sum of three numbers entered by the user in textboxes

```
function sum() {    
        var text1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('text1').value),
        text2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('text2').value),
        text3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('text3').value);
        var result = text1 + text2 + text3;

        if(!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = result;
        }
```

Here is the HTML code where I want the result shown - straight after 
'Magic Number Is:'

```
<div class="output">
<b>Magic number is:<span id="output"></span><br />
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Quote the name of the id - it's not a variable: `document.getElementById('output')`

Comment: Looks pretty much like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26030882/218196. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: Not your issue, but you should [always use the radix parameter with `parseInt`](http://davidwalsh.name/parseint-radix)

Comment: Thank you Andy! I had forgotten to quote the name of the id

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the quotes.

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result.
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` is not well written ;)

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
```